# Satisfying member declared in protocol with member of subtype or conforming type

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose I want to do protocol-oriented-programming and I have protocols:

```
protocol BehaviorA {
    var date: NSDate {get}
    var name: String {get}
}

protocol BehaviorB {
    var creationInfo: BehaviorA {get}
}
```

I would like to have one version of this ownership model implemented with the core data. The core data wants a specific class for each model entity, so I create a class `ActualA` and `ActualB`:

```
class ActualA: NSManagedObject, BehaviorA {
    @NSManaged var date: NSDate
    @NSManaged var name: String
}

class ActualB: NSManagedObject, BehaviorB {
    @NSManaged var creationInfo: ActualA
}
```

Because of the data model relationship, the var is of type ActualA. However, I get a compile-time error saying that `ActualB` doesn't conform to `BehaviorB`, and it goes away if I re-type the `creationInfo` as `BehaviorA`.

However, I would expect that there's a way to say, this variable satisfies the protocol member because its type is at least as restrictive as that declared in the protocol. Can I do this in any way? Any PoP-fans have advice on how to accomplish protocols which own one another yet the conforming types would like to be specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy.  We just need to change `BehaviorB` protocol to use an `associatedType`:

```
protocol BehaviorB {
    associatedtype Info: BehaviorA

    var creationInfo: Info {get}
}
```

Where we can call `Info` whatever we want (whatever is helpful to indicate to any implementers of `BehaviorB` what this type represents).

This is sort of like using generics.  Here `Info` can be any type, as long as that type is `BehaviorA`, a protocol inheriting `BehaviorA`, or a concrete type which implements or inherits `BehaviorA`.

Comment: Thanks for this info, I didn't know about associated types. That makes a lot of sense but when I tried it, I got `Property cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C`. I have the `@objc` attribute on `BehaviorB` because it is a requirement for the dependency injection library i'm using. Any way to allow both?

Comment: based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228546/protocol-with-associatedtype-doesnt-play-nice-with-optional i believe it's not possible. I will look for workaround.